# Remove file with double quotes in filename (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, filenames

I have 2 files on a Windows 7 32-bit pc that are named:

- Caecilia PMN A"
- ._Caecilia PMN A"

I'm trying to delete them, but I'm not succeeding because of the double quotes. The files are not locked, I have permission to delete them, the path to the files is not deep.

I've tried:

- the DelinvFile tool at http://www.purgeie.com/delinv/
- the tips at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320081
- UnxUtils rm -rf

Does anyone know what else I can try?

Comment: Have you tried boot into linux live and delete it?

Comment: did you try fileAssasin (part of Malware bytes) or "Unlocker"? or any tools that you have with your virus protection stuff designed for removing stuff that uses various methods to keep from being deleted?

Answer (score 3):

All files are going to have a DOS alias (assuming 8.3 file naming isn't disabled). You can use this to manipulate the files also.

Steps as follows:

- Find out what the short name is (using dir/x)
- Delete it using the short name
- In the screenshot below you can see that the GenerateMachineKey.exe is the only one that needs a short 8.3 name (highlighted)

[image: Screenshot of folder showing how to get the short DOS name]